# java kml doesn't read greek characters

Tags: java, kml

I would like to ask for a solution for the problem that I will display below.
I read a kml file that has greek characters with kml.unmarshal and I receive those characters Ξ”Ξ—Ξ�Ξ�Ξ£Ξ™Ξ�Ξ™ Ξ§Ξ©Ξ΅Ξ�Ξ™

```
    final Kml kml = Kml.unmarshal(new File("something.kml"));
    final de.micromata.opengis.kml.v_2_2_0.Document document = (de.micromata.opengis.kml.v_2_2_0.Document) kml.getFeature();
    List<Feature> t = document.getFeature();
    for (Object o : t) {
        PointOfInterest poi = new PointOfInterest();

        Folder f = (Folder) o;
        List<Feature> tg = f.getFeature();
        for (Object ftg : tg) {

            Placemark g = (Placemark) ftg;
            ExtendedData extdat = g.getExtendedData();
            List<SchemaData> list = extdat.getSchemaData();
            List<SimpleData> list2 = list.get(0).getSimpleData();
            for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
                SimpleData dat = list2.get(i);
                //  System.out.println(dat.getName() + "  -  " + dat.getValue());
                if (dat.getName().equals("newcat"))
                   if (dat.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Ελληνικοι χαρακτηρες"){...}}}
```

The code is not mine and I try to find out why dat.getvalue has the following content Ξ”Ξ—Ξ�Ξ�Ξ£Ξ™Ξ�Ξ™ Ξ§Ξ©Ξ΅Ξ�Ξ™ when it has greek characters.

**Edit:**

I tried to use

**final Kml kml = Kml.unmarshal(new FileInputStream(new File("something.kml")), "UTF8"))**

and I get the following error.Any idea why?

no suitable method found for unmarshal(FileInputStream,String)
    method Kml.unmarshal(InputStream) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Kml.unmarshal(String) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Kml.unmarshal(File) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Kml.unmarshal(File,boolean) is not applicable
      (actual argument FileInputStream cannot be converted to File by method invocation conversion)

unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

';' expected

Comment: You obviously don't specify the correct encoding when reading the XML...

Comment: It's an encoding problem. Where do you see those characters after unmarschal? Do you print/display them somewere else?

Comment: and how can I do that?
I use
final Kml kml = Kml.unmarshal(new File("something.kml"));
        final de.micromata.opengis.kml.v_2_2_0.Document document = (de.micromata.opengis.kml.v_2_2_0.Document) kml.getFeature();

Comment: Try and see whether Kml (I don't know the API) has a method accepting a `Reader` as an argument; configure that `Reader` to use the correct encoding

Comment: Could you write down you're imports? Also have you tried other suggestion? "unreported exception FileNotFoundException", "';' expected" could you fix that insted of writing it down?

Answer (score 0):

At the page:
http://labs.micromata.de/projects/jak/quickstart.html
You might also see there is specified encoding in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

when they are using:

```
final Kml kml = Kml.unmarshal(new File("HelloKml.kml"));
```

That mght be the case.

Comment: My bad. That was not valid offcourse. Edited - now it should be ok.  http://www.nilab.info/docs/jak091130/de/micromata/opengis/kml/v_2_2_0/Kml.html

Comment: i tried what konradOliwer suggested and I receive an error that I mention in my first post with edit.Could you please check it?

Comment: Errr, you can't specify an encoding when using a FileInputStream

Comment: and how can I do it without a fileinputstream?

Comment: Goog point @fge. Sorry I must be tired, I forgot to add InputStreamReader. Hope it's fine now

Comment: Now i have a compile error 
no suitable method found for unmarshal(inputstreamreader)

Comment: Removed it, it seams it wont work since it's not steam anymore. Perhaps my second answer might help you.

Comment: It had already the encoding="UTF-8" in the kml file..Any other idea?

Comment: Perhaps consol font doesn't have greek characteres.